# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to read textfile into hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, text-files

I have the following code

```
while(((line = in.readLine()) != null))
                {
            String[] val = line.split("<>");

            courses.put(val[0], val[1]);
```

and this is the text i'm trying to read

```
1<>CIS 101-1
2<>CIS 101-2
3<>CIS 231-1
4<>CIS 231-2
5<>CIS 234-1
6<>CIS 234-2
```

i get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying to run the program at line

```
 courses.put(val[0], val[1]);
```

can anyone offer any help?

Comment: did you look in the stacktrace which line it is? Maybe it has something to do with the regex. The Argument for split is not easily a String, its a Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those lines should produce an array of length 2.

Make sure you don't have a blank line in the end of the file.

You could for instance skip lines that doesn't conform to the pattern by adding something like

```
while (...) {

    if (!line.contains("<>"))
        continue;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Your fix has just saved me hours and hours of headache. Honestly I had no idea that there could be an end line with blank space... Thank you very much kind sir!

Answer (score 2):

One of your lines doesn't have `<>` on it. Possibly the last line. Do you have an end-of-line after line 6? You should probably write more defensive code - trim each line you read (to get rid of any leading/trailing whitespace) and then ignore the line if it has zero length.

Comment: there isn't a blank line at the end. how do i trim each line?

Comment: add try catch and look which line it is

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the you read an empty line at the end, so `val[1]` is beyond the end of the array!